# Change of order of filters speeds up the query in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I use Entity Framework to fetch data from my database. For that purpose, I use

```
return await _context.vw_Attribute_Entities
     .Where(x => x.ProjectID == id && x.EntityID == entityId)
     .Select(dt => new DataTypesDetails() { ... }
```

This thing was fast and good but out of nowhere (didn't make any changes on backend side nor data base) it became slowly and needs more than 30 seconds to return result. However, if I reorder the filter like

```
return await _context.vw_Attribute_Entities
     .Where(x => x.EntityID == entityId && x.ProjectID == id)
     .Select(dt => new DataTypesDetails() { ... }
```

it speeds up again. This query returns 90 rows at max and the time it needs is ~1 second. I had a problem like this multiple times and the solution was to wrap this as a stored procedure in my database and execute that stored procedure on .NET side, but I'm curious about why does this happen?

p.s I have a SQL Server as a database.

Comment: (i think) it means `EntityID == entityId` has much less row count than that of `ProjectID == id`

Comment: Makes sense. If so, why did it work 1 hour ago with the first implementation?

Comment: *didn't make any changes on backend side nor data base* does this mean nobody is updating the database? the database is completely owned by you? suggest log `_context.vw_Attribute_Entities
     .Count(x => x.foo == bar`).

Comment: Yes, nobody is updating the database but there was one user that was using the same view as me on another device. That will work, everything works fine with the view. The thing is, it became slowly out of nowhere and reorder of the filter speeds it up. I had multiple times this happen to me. It's weird because if I reorder the filters now and deploy, it'll become slow again within 2-3 days and I'll need to reorder (return back to the first version) the filter again in order to speed it up and a loop with reordering of filters by each 3rd day will start

Comment: do you have sqlserver profiler and check the sql and execute time, and connections count? i worry that your issue is not reproducible.